# How do I remove these apostrophes from the string

Tags: python, string, operators, apostrophe

```
print("ENEMY Health is ", (int(ehealth), ' / ', (int(emaxHealth))), sep='')
```

Should look like:
`ENEMY Health is 100 / 100`

but it looks like this:
`ENEMY Health is (100, ' / ', 100)`

Whats the go with this?

Comment: if some answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 2):

By enclosing the health ratio in brackets, you are creating on the fly a Python [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Calling `print` on that tuple will result in printing its string representation.
So you have three elements enclosed in brackets and separated by commas, two of them being numbers (no quotes), and the one in the middle being a string (hence the quotes).

Your line of code could be:

```
print("ENEMY Health is {0} / {1}".format(ehealth, emaxHealth))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets present inside the print function.

```
>>> ehealth = 100
>>> emaxHealth = 100
>>> print("ENEMY Health is ",str(ehealth),' / ',str(emaxHealth), sep='')
ENEMY Health is 100 / 100
```

OR

```
>>> print("ENEMY Health is "+str(ehealth)+' / '+str(emaxHealth))
ENEMY Health is 100 / 100
```

OR

```
>>> print("ENEMY Health is {} / {}".format(ehealth, emaxHealth))
ENEMY Health is 100 / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Im more familiar with java is but I I think maybe change to quote's!   print("ENEMY Health is ",(int(ehealth), "/" ,(int(emaxhealth)))) or take out quotes and apostrophies and leave the / where it is. hope this helps!